# requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent not working in WebView

Tags: android, android-listview, webview

I have following structure in my application.

ListView >LinearLayout(ListItem) > TextView and WebView child of LinearLayout.

Now the problem is my Webview is not able to scroll when i do it first time. From second time it is able to scroll well. After extending LinearLayout i could see first time event is going their and my WebView is getting Action_Canceled in onTouch.

TO get rid of it i wrote following function but it does not seems to have any effect. I also tried to use onInterceptTouchEvent() but it does not seems to me helping me.

```
public void goingCrazy(ViewGroup v) {
        v.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        if (!(v instanceof Contacts_Custom_Layouts.Custom_ViewFlipper)) {
            goingCrazy((ViewGroup) v.getParent());
        }
    }
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome. This is really making me crazy so i gave the function name same.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586488/requestdisallowintercepttouchevent-does-not-work-unless-selecting-view-first?

Comment: Hi, I read it and i tried it but yet it seems to have problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's been two years but I just encountered this problem and solved it adding `view.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(MotionEvent.obtain(1,1,1,0.0f,0.0f,0)))`; inside the ontouch before setting `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent`